# SSIS pack taking data from json source using order by in variable don't bring all data

Tags: json, ssis, package.json

I have one package in SSIS, when a run the pack taking the data from Jsons source, via the Kingswaysoft JSON Source Component, with domain parameter is brought to me

domain=XXXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

1000 rows ..

when I use the same package and include the order by inside the parameter the data is bring less data

Does someone know why the order by in the JSON source is changing the result?

domain=XXXXXXXXXXXXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA^ORDERBYdatacreatedon

950 rows ....

[image]

Comment: I would attempt to identify if this is an issue with the source component or the source API. Use Fiddler/postman/curl and see whether that results in different length documents served with/without the ORDER BY clause. If they both yield the same length document, then I'd contact Kingswaysoft and see whether it's a bug in their component. Conceptually, I can't see how adding an ORDER BY would affect results in either case. Instead, I'd be more inclined to look at what the domain of data you're pulling back - perhaps a ticket got closed, item was sold, etc and the different is due to time factor

Comment: The data when I run with the order by I didn't receive the data and when a run without the data appears, and when I back the data is there again. 
because this the problem is not with da data change inside the source I think. 
Maybe can be a problem with the kingswaysoft like you say.
Did you say to use the (  Fiddler/postman/curl ) what is that exactly ?